Compare two strings that are not the same in Excel and Ouput True/False depending on contents
Table in questions has 3 rows, one of the rows has: applicable, NA, Tailored in it's columns. The other column has the words: applicable, Not Applicable, Heading, Deleted/Reserved"
I have figured out the conditionals that work for me, however I do not know how to get excel to check these conditionals to Output True False. i cannot just modify the cell contents to make them match formatting for reasons.
The logic statements are:
Applicable + applicable = TRUE; OR Heading + NA = TRUE; RO Deleted/Reserved + NA = TRUE; OR Not Applicable + NA = TRUE;
otherwise it should be FALSE. So just checking for the TRUE statements should be good enough in this case.
so the two parts of my question here are a) how to get excel to check the multiple statements together and b) how to get excel to compare 2 different strings and output TRUE without those strings being identical.

You could use an (embedded) IF or IFS (newer versions), or you could do INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP. Is there anything you've tried yourself so far?

Post few of sample data.

right now I can't even get excel to do a SINGLE comparison I.E IF A1 contains "FART" and B2 contains "DUMB"' then C1 is TRUE. - attempting step by step here. We have this statement that doesnt work: =IF(D3= ''Heading'' H3=''NA'', TRUE, FALSE) - which I assume is a syntax error I am not sure how to resolve. Once I have that working, it shouldnt be too difficult to use a nested IF or an OR statement I presume.. i.e. I am struggling even with the creating the - IF blank AND blank are true statement

=IF(AND(D3="Heading",H3="NA"),TRUE,FALSE) -is what I got to work. so now its just getting the nested portion to work

Please edit your question instead of adding infromation in comments

You could use something like this:
=IF(OR(AND(A10=$A$1,A9=$B$1),AND(A10=$A$2,A9=$B$2),AND(A10=$A$3,A9=$B$2),AND(A10=$A$4,A9=$B$2)),"TRUE","FALSE")

Or you could replace the references with the actual statements.


We could use FIND in this manner to find a match: ISNUMBER(FIND(word1, col1)). FIND is case sensitive. As shown in the results, terms are matched anywhere in the list, not as words surrounded by spaces etc.
So, if the data is entered as in the second figure (list in A2:A12 and words in E2:E5), here's how ISNUMBER(FIND… will look:

Since we wants pairwise match, we can multiply the results from FIND,  (AND(TRUE, TRUE)) = TRUE * TRUE = 1), we set the row to TRUE if at least one pair matches. MMULT will give sum of all TRUE/FALSE per row.
=IF(
    MMULT(
        ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(E2:E5), A2:A12)) *
            ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(F2:F5), B2:B12)),
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(E2:E5), , 1, 0)
    ),
    TRUE
)


